# Computing angle of rotation and scaling factor directly from given transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, geometric-transform

I have a simple 2D transformation matrix performing rotation combined with scaling
    \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
Where the scalar $r$ is multiplied with
    \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
Is there a simple method that can be performed on the input matrix to compute $r$ and $\theta$ directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to Henrik's version, perhaps more easily understandable is the use of

```
{Q, R} = QRDecomposition[{{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
(* {{{1/Sqrt[2], -(1/Sqrt[2])}, {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}}, {{Sqrt[2],0}, {0, Sqrt[2]}}} *)
```

Q is a rotation matrix and R contains the scaling

```
Solve[RotationMatrix[\[CurlyPhi] ] == Q, \[CurlyPhi]][[1]] /.C[1] -> 0 
(*{\[CurlyPhi] -> \[Pi]/4} *)
```

Comment: Very good, indeed.

Comment: @Henrik: Thanks, what is needed for the direct solution is the the polar decomposition of a matrix, but I didn't find a Mathematica implementation...

Comment: I could not find it either. =/

Comment: @Henrik: For "regular" matrix M one could take `S = MatrixPower[Transpose[M].M, 1/2];
R = Inverse[Transpose[M]].S(* rotationmatrix R^t.R=Identity*)` with polar decomposition `M=R.S`

Answer (score 2):

```
m = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}};
FullSimplify @ Solve[Transpose[RotationMatrix[θ]].ScalingMatrix[{s1, s2}] == m, 
  {s1, s2, θ}, Reals] /. C[1] -> 0 // TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left\{\text{s1}\to -\sqrt{2},\text{s2}\to -\sqrt{2},\theta \to
>    -\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right\},\left\{\text{s1}\to \sqrt{2},\text{s2}\to
>    \sqrt{2},\theta \to \frac{\pi }{4}\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Why `ConjugateTranspose`? Any problem about `m = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}; FullSimplify@
 Solve[ScalingMatrix[{s1, s2}] . RotationMatrix[\[Theta]] == 
    m && -Pi < \[Theta] < Pi, {s1, s2, \[Theta]}, Reals]`?

Comment: Thank you @yode; you are right; no need for `Conjugate` here.

Comment: So you replaced it with another unnecessary `Transpose`? :)

Comment: I add a `-Pi < θ < Pi` because trigonometric functions are periodic functions, which has nothing to do with `Transpose`. `Transpose` or `Conjugate` before it is totally no need in your code

Comment: @yode, I was trying to get the solution `{Sqrt[2], Pi/4}` from Ulrich's answer. Without `Transpose` signs are flipped.

Comment: You may not understand the [rotation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKMgp.png), it doesn't matter if the sign is positive or negative, it is all correct in this question. Just the direction of the rotation matrix is different

Answer (score 2):

## Solution one

This is your `mat`:

```
MatrixForm[mat = {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

$\small \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

And this is **the angle of rotation**(Positive is counterclockwise, negative is counterclockwise):

```
Arg[mat.{1, 0}.{1, I}]
```

$-\frac{\pi }{4}$

This is **the scale on each axis**:

```
Eigenvalues[mat.Inverse[mat/Sqrt[Det[mat]]]]
```

$\left\{\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}\right\}$

---

## Solution two

As [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/computing-angle-of-rotation-and-scaling-factor-directly-from-given-transformatio/174018?noredirect=1#comment456665_173941), this is rotation matrix is:

```
R = Inverse[Transpose[mat]].MatrixPower[Transpose[mat].mat, 1/2]
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

We can get two scaling matrix generally:

```
scaleLeft = MatrixPower[mat.Transpose[mat], 1/2]
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

This mean $\rm mat=scaleLeft.R$

```
scaleRight = MatrixPower[Transpose[mat].mat, 1/2]
```

$\begin{pmatrix}
 \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

This mean $\rm mat=R.scaleRight $. But in this case, the `scaleRight` equal to `scaleLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to apply this function:

```
{#[[2, 1, 1]], -ArcTan @@ (#[[1]].#Transpose[[[3]]])[[1]]} &[SingularValueDecomposition[#]] &
```

A bit simpler, using complex numbers:

```
f = AbsArg[({1, I}.#)[[1]]] &
f[{{1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

> $\left\{\sqrt{2},-\frac{\pi }{4}\right\}$

**General case:**

A random scale-rotation:

```
scale = If[Variance[Diagonal[S]] < $MachinePrecision^2,
  Mean[Diagonal[S]],
  $Failed
  ]
```

First we compute the polar decomposition of `M`

```
{U, Σ, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[M];
R = U.Transpose[V];
S = V.Σ.Transpose[V];
```

Checking its validity:

```
Norm[R.S - M, "Frobenius"]
Norm[Transpose[R].R - IdentityMatrix[dim], "Frobenius"]
Norm[S - Transpose[S], "Frobenius"]
```

> 2.01949*10^-15
>
> 6.36666*10^-16
>
> 7.11972*10^-16

Everything seems to be good. `R` is the rotation matrix we are looking for. If `S` is a mupltiple of the identy matrix then this multiple is the scaling factor. Otherwise, we have non-uniform scalings.

```
scale = If[
  Norm[Mean[Diagonal[S]] IdentityMatrix[dim] - S, 
    "Frobenius"] < $MachinePrecision^2,
  Mean[Diagonal[S]],
  $Failed
  ]
```

Comment: When the rotation matrix is `RotationMatrix[280 \[Degree]]` your `ArcTan` cannot get the right angle.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I think a `Transpose` was missing.

Comment: [No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qE0MV.png), I don't think `ArcTan` and do this. :)

Comment: It should. It is the two-argument version of ˋArcTanˋ.

Comment: And I would recommend `Arg` here

Comment: `ArcTan[x,y] == Arg[x + I y]`, so it does the job without conversion.